# Assert number of elements in inner collection for every item in outer collection

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I want to check if every item in collection has collection that have some numbers of elements. For now I am doing that in the following way:

```
// Given
CollectionGenerator collectionGenerator = new CollectionGenerator (outerCollectionSize, innerCollectionSize);

// When
ICollection<SomeEntity> outerCollection = collectionGenerator.GenerateCollection();

// Then         
foreach (SomeEntity someEntity in outerCollection)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(innerCollectionSize, someEntity.InnerCollection.Count);
}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [`AllItemsConstraint`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/AllItemsConstraint) and do something like this:

```
Assert.That(outerCollection.Select(c => c.InnerCollection).ToList(),
            Has.All.Count.EqualTo(innerCollectionSize));
```

This gives a slightly nicer message when the test fails, e.g.:

```
Expected: all items property Count equal to 2
But was:  < < 1, 2 >, < 1, 2, 3 > >
```

*Note that the `ToList` is important, as enumerables don't have a `Count` property.*

As per [Chris'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768779/chris) suggestion, you could also do:

```
Assert.That(outerCollection.Select(c => c.InnerCollection),
            Has.All.With.Exactly(innerCollectionSize).Items);
```

If you did want to keep the loop, you should embed it in an [`Assert.Multiple`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Multiple-Asserts) (only available in NUnit 3) so that you get all of the failures, rather than just the first one:

```
Assert.Multiple(() =>
{
    foreach (SomeEntity someEntity in outerCollection)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(innerCollectionSize, someEntity.InnerCollection.Count);
    }
});
```

Comment: To avoid the `.ToList()` I think you could instead do `Has.All.Exactly(innerCollectionSize).Items`. =) With love from Leeds!

Comment: Justification: `Has.Count` is a synonym for `Has.Property("Count")`, which of course, IEnumerables don't have. ExactCountConstraint (`Has.Exactly(x).Items`) is intended to be implementation-independent, I think.

Comment: So you can. Very nice.

Comment: I was clearly thinking of other `.ToList` situations, where one would get: `But was:  <System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]>` or similar; instead of a nicely printed list.

Comment: As one final iteration - you could also use PropertyConstraint, instead of the LINQ on the left hand side, so all the information about what you're testing is wrapped up in the constraint. This possibly starts to get a little long-winded however, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45030496/1768779 =)

Comment: If you were to be doing this lots, you could use a [custom constraint](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Custom-Constraints) and extension method to write something like `Assert.That(outerCollection, Has.All.InnerCollectionCount.EqualTo(innerCollectionSize));`

Comment: `Has.All.With` is documented as "With is currently a NOP - reserved for future use"

Comment: Do you have a link for that? The source code would appear to disagree: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Constraints/Operators/WithOperator.cs The docs might need updating.

Answer (score 1):

One final iteration on [Scroog1's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245027/scroog1) answer - to be more 'semantically assertive' - you could also do the below:

```
Assert.That(outerCollection, 
            Has.All.Property(nameof(CollectionGenerator.InnerCollection))
                   .Exactly(innerCollectionSize).Items);
```

This gives an error message something like:

```
1) Failed : NUnitLite.Tests.Program.MyTest
   Expected: all items property InnerCollection exactly 2 items
   But was:  < <CollectionGenerator> >
```

Which could possibly be useful, depending on how useful your `CollectionGenerator.ToString()` method is. I like it, as it's explicit just from the error message now that you're testing the `InnerCollection` property - although it perhaps does start to get a little long-winded.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
Assert.IsTrue(outerCollection.All(inner => inner.Length == innerCollectionSize);
```

But it basically amounts to the same thing, the loop is just not explicit; the outercollection will be iterated and every innercollection will be verified.